Error installing NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 22.04
I'm trying to install CUDA 12.1 on Ubuntu 22.04. I'm on a laptop with a 2060.
These are the commands I have used. The first ones are to uninstall my current cuda drivers and the next ones are to install CUDA 12.1 (i got these commands from this):
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "*cufft*" "*curand*" "*cusolver*" "*cusparse*" "*npp*" "*nvjpeg*" "cuda*" "nsight*"
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
sudo apt-get autoremove

wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.1.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local_12.1.0-530.30.02-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local_12.1.0-530.30.02-1_amd64.deb
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda

With the last command I received the following error:
dpkg: dependency issues prevent configuration of cuda-drivers-530:
  cuda-drivers-530 depends on nvidia-dkms-530 (>= 530.30.02); however:
  The `nvidia-dkms-530' package is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers-530 (--configure):
  dependency issues - left unconfigured
Configuring libxml2:i386 (2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.4) ...
An "apport" report was not written because the error message indicates that it is an error message associated with a previous failure.
                                            Configuring cuda-compiler-12-1 (12.1.0-1)...
Configuring libxcb-dri3-0:i386 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
Configuring libx11-xcb1:i386 (2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.3) ...
Configuring cuda-libraries-12-1 (12.1.0-1)...
Configuring libnvjitlink-dev-12-1 (12.1.55-1)...
Configuring libgbm1:i386 (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2) ...
Configuring libcusparse-dev-12-1 (12.0.2.55-1)...
Configuring libcurand-dev-12-1 (10.3.2.56-1)...
Configuring libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.4-1build1) ...
dpkg: dependency issues prevent nvidia-driver-530 from being configured:
  nvidia-driver-530 depends on nvidia-dkms-530 (=530.30.02-0ubuntu1); however:
  The `nvidia-dkms-530' package is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-530 (--configure):
  dependency issues - left unconfigured
An "apport" report was not written because the error message indicates that it is an error message associated with a previous failure.
                                            Configuring libcublas-dev-12-1 (12.1.0.26-1)...
Configuring libxxf86vm1:i386 (1:1.1.4-1build3) ...
Configuring libegl-mesa0:i386 (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2) ...
Configuring libxfixes3:i386 (1:6.0.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency issues prevent configuration of cuda-drivers:
  cuda-drivers depends on cuda-drivers-530 (=530.30.02-1); however:
  The `cuda-drivers-530' package is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers (--configure):
  dependency issues - left unconfigured
No "apport" report was written because the value of "MaxReports" has already been reached
          Configuring libnvidia-decode-530:i386 (530.30.02-0ubuntu1) ...
Configuring cuda-opencl-dev-12-1 (12.1.56-1)...
Configuring libllvm15:i386 (1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) ...
Configuring libegl1:i386 (1.4.0-1) ...
Configuring cuda-libraries-dev-12-1 (12.1.0-1)...
Configuring libnvidia-encode-530:i386 (530.30.02-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency issues prevent configuration of cuda-runtime-12-1:
  cuda-runtime-12-1 depends on cuda-drivers (>= 530.30.02); however:
  The `cuda-drivers' package is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-runtime-12-1 (--configure):
  dependency issues - left unconfigured
Configuring libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2) ...
No "apport" report was written because the value of "MaxReports" has already been reached
          Configuring cuda-visual-tools-12-1 (12.1.0-1)...
dpkg: dependency issues prevent configuration of cuda-12-1:
  cuda-12-1 depends on cuda-runtime-12-1 (>= 12.1.0); however:
  Package `cuda-runtime-12-1' is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-12-1 (--configure):
  dependency issues - left unconfigured
Configuring libglx-mesa0:i386 (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2) ...
No "apport" report was written because the value of "MaxReports" has already been reached
          Configuring libglx0:i386 (1.4.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency issues prevent cuda configuration:
  cuda depends on cuda-12-1 (>= 12.1.0); however:
  Package `cuda-12-1' is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing cuda package (--configure):
  dependency issues - left unconfigured
dpkg: dependency issues prevent configuration of cuda-demo-suite-12-1:
  cuda-demo-suite-12-1 depends on cuda-runtime-12-1; however:
  Package `cuda-runtime-12-1' is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-demo-suite-12-1 (--configure):
  dependency issues - left unconfigured
Configuring cuda-tools-12-1 (12.1.0-1)...
No "apport" report was written because the value of "MaxReports" has already been reached
          No "apport" report was written because the value of "MaxReports" has already been reached
                   Configuring cuda-toolkit-12-1 (12.1.0-1)...
Configuring libgl1:i386 (1.4.0-1) ...
Configuring libnvidia-gl-530:i386 (530.30.02-0ubuntu1) ...
Configuring libnvidia-fbc1-530:i386 (530.30.02-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6)...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1)...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1)...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3)...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3)...
Processing even triggers to initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4)...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-27-generic
Errors found when processing:
  nvidia-dkms-530
  cuda-drivers-530
  nvidia-driver-530
  cuda drivers
  cuda-runtime-12-1
  cuda-12-1
  cuda
  cuda-demo-suite-12-1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Finally, I have decided to install CUDA 11.8, but I get an error when I run that file. I have post the error on this

Dup of answers 1077061 or 1219761 on this site. On a clean machine, do a normal Nvidia driver install of latest from the standard repos. The hwe package will download the 6.5 kernel and the gcc-12 (but NOT make it the default) and should successfully use the gcc-12 to build the kernel's module. Use .run script, skip nvidia driver offer, use options to avoid system areas bin and lib (use your /usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin and /usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64, and updates won't break anything.

Finally I found a guide to install it and i could install it suscessfully. This is the guide

Did you tried sudo apt --fix-broken install?
If the command above won't help, try to uninstall again with commands:
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt remove nvidia-*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*

And install it in a hard way. It's may be not a complete walkthrough for you but it must give you help for many causes and steps that could go wrong with your installation process.
Install dependences:
sudo apt-get install g++ freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev

Check gcc compiler version:
gcc --version

And install corresponding Bazel version (check version compatability HERE):
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg
curl -fsSL https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor >bazel-archive-keyring.gpg
sudo mv bazel-archive-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/bazel-archive-keyring.gpg] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc
/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bazel-***YOUR-VERSION***
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/bazel-1.0.0 /usr/bin/bazel

Download compatable CUDA version (check version from the link above):
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/YOUR-VERSION/local_installers/cuda_***YOUR-VERSION***_linux.run

Run installer to install CUDA drivers:
sudo sh cuda_***YOUR-VERSION***_linux.run

Setup paths for the tools:
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-***YOUR-VERSION***/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-***YOUR-VERSION***/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
sudo ldconfig

Download CuDNN From Nvidia website (check version from the link above):
https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/***YOUR-VERSION***/***YOUR-VERSION***/cudnn-***YOUR-VERSION***-linux-x64-***YOUR-VERSION***.tgz
tar -xzvf cudnn-***YOUR-VERSION***-linux-x64-***YOUR-VERSION***.tgz

Copy CuDNN files to Nvidia toolkit directory (paths may be vary):
sudo cp -P cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda-***YOUR-VERSION***/include
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda-***YOUR-VERSION***/lib64/
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda-***YOUR-VERSION***/lib64/libcudnn*

Add PATH for CuDNN (paths may be vary):
sudo nano /home/username/.bashrc
Insert in the end of the config file the row:
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-***YOUR-VERSION***/bin:$PATH"

And reboot PC. After reboot enter nvidia-smi command and you should see driver info and installed CUDA version.
IF ERROR in Nvidia logs in nvidia-installer.log
Check the logs in /var/log/nvidia-installer.log or /var/log/cuda-installer.log
enter image description here
Tupicaly the Error and screenshot causes Nouveau kernel driver. To bypass the error you need to do the next steps:

Purge nvidia again with the first steps

Uncomment the line WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Create file with command: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf and add lines:
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0

save with combination ctrl+O

Run the command to apply the changes: sudo update-initramfs -u

Reboot PC

Do again all the steps from the step Run installer to install CUDA drivers


If the error appeared in logs again:

boot in Ubuntu recovery menu (tap ESC right after PC start booting)

Enter terminal under root

Do step Run installer to install CUDA drivers

Boot back in a normal interface

Do the rest steps to setup all completely



I have decided to install CUDA 11.8 instead of CUDA 12.1. After done the steps you said, the error Nouveau appeared. After fix that error i get another error. I posted on NVIDIA forum here

I can feel your pain. I've written this guide based on my own experience of installing the different versions of Nvidia software on different Ubuntu versions (18.04, 20.04, 22.04). And it worked for my hardware and my drivers versions. But unfortunately for some reason, there can be differences based on hardware, kernel version, etc. Also I will recommend recheck all the paths from the guide as I faced that on different OS versions they are the different.
